# CSS Positioning issues. Detaily explained

Tags: html, css, division

I have 2 issues and can't fix them.I am trying to make the same design as [image].

I can't adjust the box in the header , to stay next to my headline tags.And another issue is that , I can't position all my content elements in 1 line. One is upper , another is with 5 pixels under the other..I've tried to show the issues with Paint [image: Issues] 
There's my code , I`ll be glad if anyone can help me 
HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>Newspaper</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <hgroup>
            <h2>THE OLD POST</h2>
            <h3>ILLUSTRATED WEEKLY NEWSPAPER</h3>
            <div class="header-Box">
                <strong>This is a story about one pig</strong>
            </div>
        </hgroup>
    </header>

    <div class="infoBorder">
        <span>Est.1896</span>
        <span>Wednesday,November 24,1892</span>
        <span>Price 6d</span>
    </div>

    <div id="main-Content">
        <h1>INSERT YOUR HEADLINE</h1>
        <div class="parent-content">
        <div class="content">
            <strong>Bacon ipsum dolor amet beef strip steak beef ribs ham, porchetta ground round ham hock turducken prosciutto kevin swine.</strong>
            <p>
            Flank turkey venison frankfurter spare ribs drumstick ball tip rump porchetta kielbasa swine pork turducken. Turkey frankfurter leberkas flank pork belly porchetta pork landjaeger beef ribeye alcatra picanha hamburger tongue. Cow bacon ribeye sirloin pancetta sausage pork loin jerky short ribs corned beef biltong hamburger.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <strong>Hamburger pastrami strip steak turkey landjaeger sirloin tail pig shoulder tri-tip. Tail swine flank meatball turkey andouille drumstick pancetta sausage tri-tip spare ribs ribeye.</strong>
            <p>
            Jowl turkey tri-tip salami. Porchetta fatback corned beef, andouille ham hock chuck cow short loin bresaola. Landjaeger sausage spare ribs kielbasa filet mignon capicola biltong. Sausage t-bone doner hamburger, tri-tip cupim andouille.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <strong>Jerky cow meatloaf pastrami landjaeger bacon ground round shank venison jowl pork belly biltong capicola kevin pig. Filet mignon alcatra pancetta strip steak pork belly.</strong>
            <p>
            Alcatra pastrami shoulder doner brisket spare ribs turducken chuck kevin tenderloin flank. Pig hamburger tenderloin, pork cow pancetta ground round kielbasa bresaola shank fatback sirloin beef ribs tail beef. Chicken ham hock salami shoulder, andouille fatback filet mignon bresaola venison.
            </p>
        </div>
        <img src="http://www.gif-favicon.com/images/flowers/pink-flowers-transparent-clipart-0400-10054.gif" />
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

AND MY CSS CODE:

```
body {
  background-image: url("img/news_background.jpg");
}
header {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
}
div.header-Box {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
}
h1,
h2,
h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0px;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0px;
}
div.infoBorder {
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
span {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 160px;
}
div#main-Content {
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
}
div.content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 240px;
  height: 280px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your css this

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t8aqurmu/)**

```
div.content {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

=== **2nd issue** is this  resolve

**Change your html this**

```
<header>
        <hgroup>
            <h2>THE OLD POST</h2>
            <h3>ILLUSTRATED WEEKLY NEWSPAPER</h3>

        </hgroup>
        <div class="header-Box">
                <strong>This is a story about one pig</strong>
            </div>
    </header>
```

**and write this  css**

```
header {
    text-align: center;
}
hgroup {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
div.header-Box {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t8aqurmu/2/)**

Comment: Man thank you , that helped me for the one issue.If you have any ideas for the first one , please share your idea with me.I`ll be glad and mark your answer as checked as well.

Comment: @Nasco.Chachev Can u change your html

Comment: What do you mean , bro? I mean your vertically-align helped me to position the divs in the same line , but I still miss my header-box issue. I want to place it right next to my headlines, I've posted an original design.Please check the link

Comment: Thanks a lot bro , god bless you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
float: left;
```

...is the key. Just add it to your Paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

```
<hgroup> {
    positon: relative;
}

add:

div.header-Box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 40px;
}

div.content {
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Hm... it's not satisfying. It doesn't work the way I want. Your code place that header-Box below the headlines.I want to place it right next to headlines and all goes in the middle of the page.